# dbus session connections: connecting dbus signals with qt slots, how can it be done?

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qdbus, qtdbus

So, for the life of me, I can't get my object to connect to the session bus.  So, I'm trying to connect "wakeup" of "my_obj" to the dBus signal "profileChanged".  But, even though I'm sure (via qbusviewer) that this signal is being emitted, "wakeup" will not run.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
const QString service = "org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement";
const QString path = "/org/kde/Solid/PowerManagement";
const QString interface = "org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement";    

QDBusConnection bus = QDBusConnection::sessionBus();

if (!bus.isConnected()) 
{
      qDebug() << "Can't connect to the D-Bus session bus.\n";
}                

class my_wake_up_class : public QObject
{
      Q_OBJECT
public slots:
      void wakeup(QString); //Does not run!
};

my_wake_up_class my_obj;

bool conn = bus.connect(service, path, interface, "profileChanged", &my_obj, SLOT(wakeup(QString)));
if (!conn) qDebug() << "not connected";
```

qDBus shows that "profileChanged" has the form "void (QString)" and I'm not getting any errors nor warnings.  Here is the qdbus output for that particular signal:

```
signal void org.kde.Solid.PowerManagement.profileChanged(QString)
```

So, I'd think this would work.  I'm sure I'm missing some minute detail that's buried deep within some documentation.  Would anybody know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

So, the good people at qtforum.org humored my ignorance.  Apparently, I needed to enable the Qt Event system.  Normally this is done by the QApplication class, which I did not include.  Once included, everything works fine.